# Error in retrieving the number of clones from one of my Git repositories

Tags: git, shell, github, ssh

I'm trying to download the number of clones of one of my repos via shell. I've followed the instructions in the [reference](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#traffic), but to no avail. This is what I do:

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/my-github-username/my-repo-name/traffic/clones
```

What I get is:

```
{
  "message": "Must have push access to repository",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-clones"
}
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this result. I've tried issuing the command from outside the repository and from within, but the result is the same. I've also tried to tell `curl` to use the SSH key associated to my account by doing:

```
curl --key ~/.ssh/id_github --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_github.pub ...
```

but the result is the same. I've also tried

```
curl -u my-github-username --key ~/.ssh/id_github --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_github.pub ...
```

But I keep getting the same result.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Since your repository is private, you will need to create a personal access token and pass that as your user in a curl request similar to this: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#basic-authentication

Comment: @Thomas5631 Thanks for the comment. However, I never said that my repository is private. It is, in fact, public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an SSH key to make an API request.  To authenticate, you need to use some sort of token, which in your case is probably going to be a personal access token.  You can create one with the `repo` scope by going into the Developer Settings page.

Once you have that token, you can run this (replacing `MY-TOKEN-HERE`):

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Token MY-TOKEN-HERE" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/my-github-username/my-repo-name/traffic/clones
```

Once you do that, you should be able to make the request successfully.